# Questions about Simmons' construction of his first construction of coequalizer for the category of $\textbf{Sets}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

The following is from Harold Simmon's *An introduction Category Theory* which contains the definition for the concepts of both equalizer and coequalizer, along with the first of two construction for the coequalizer for the category of Sets.

> $\quad$ [Simmons, **Definition 1**]  Given a parallel pair $${\stackrel{\large{A}\stackrel{\small\small f}{\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\longrightarrow}}\large{B}}{\small\small g}}$$ of arrows in a category $C$ $$\text{an equalizer} \quad \text{a coequalizer}$$ is an arrow $$S\xrightarrow{k}A \quad B\xrightarrow{k}S$$ which makes equal $f$ and $g$, and has the following universal property.
> $\quad$For each arrow $$X\xrightarrow{h}A \quad B\xrightarrow{h}X$$ which makes equal the parallel pair, there is a *unique arrow* $$X\xrightarrow{m}S \quad S\xrightarrow{m}X$$ such that $$h=k\circ m\quad h=m\circ k$$ holds.  This $m$ is the mediating arrow (or mediator) for the arrow $h$.
> $\quad$Let $S$ be an arbitrary set, and let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $S$.  This relation partition $S$ into blocks (equivalence classes).  For each $s\in S$ let $[s]$ be the block in which $s$ lives, and let $$S/\sim$$ be the set of all such blocks. Let $$S\xrightarrow{\sigma}S/\sim$$ $$S\mapsto [s]$$be the induced surjection.
> $\quad$Let $$S\xrightarrow{\sigma}X$$ be any function.  $\color{red}{The \,kernel \,of \,h \,is \,the \,relation \,\approx \,on \,S \,given \,by \,}$ $$\color{red}{s_1\approx s_2 \Longleftrightarrow h(s_1)=h(s_2).}$$ $\color{red}{for\,s_1, s_2\in S.}$  Trivially, this is an equivalence relation.
> $\quad$$\color{red}{Now\, suppose\, \approx\, includes\, \sim, \,that\, is \,S \,given \,by \,}$ $$\color{red}{s_1\sim s_2 \Longrightarrow h(s_1)=h(s_2)}$$ $\color{red}{for\,s_1, s_2\in S. }$   Under these conditions there is a commuting triangle 
> [image]

> for some unique function $h^{\sharp}$.  This function is given by $$h^{\sharp}([s])=h(s)$$ for $s\in S.$  To show that $h^{\sharp}$ is well defined; the function $\sigma$ is surjective, there can be at most one function $h^{\sharp}$ to make the diagram commute (the one in the screen shot above)  For $s_1, s_2 \in S$ we have $$[s_1]=[s_2] \Longrightarrow s_1\sim s_2\Longrightarrow h(s_1)=h(s_2)$$ to show that the suggested function $h^{\sharp}$ is well defined.  For $s\in S$ we have $$(h^{\sharp}\circ \sigma)(s)=h^{\sharp}([s])=h(s)$$ to show that the triangle commutes.

**Questions:**  The portion of the block text in red, I would like to know why in the construction, there needs to be defined two equivalence relations: $\approx$, $\sim$, and $\sim  \,\subset \,\approx$, and also why where both of the equivalence relation has to be the kernel of a function.  The other thing is, in $\color{red}{s_1\sim s_2 \Longrightarrow h(s_1)=h(s_2)}$, shouldn't the $\Longrightarrow$ be $\Longleftrightarrow$ instead?  Meaning, there is that a misprint?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\sim$ is first introduced in 2.6.6, Simmons is explaining how equivalence relations and quotients of sets relate to functions, before considering how to build the coequalizer in 2.6.7. **I think your problem is that Simmons uses $S$ for an arbitrary set in 2.6.6, but in the proof of existence of coequalizers he is going to apply it to $B$, not $S$, and the $S$ from the definition of coequalizers is $B/{\sim}$.**

Perhaps it is better to see the overall strategy for constructing $S$ and $k : B \rightarrow S$ to make a coequalizer.

1. Define, using $f$ and $g$, a purpose-made equivalence relation $\sim$ on $B$.
2. Take $S = B/{\sim}$ and $k$ to be the function mapping $b \in B$ to $[b]$, its equivalence class.
3. Given some $h : B \rightarrow X$ such that $h \circ f = h \circ g$, we require an $m : S \rightarrow X$ such that $m \circ k = h$, unique with this property.
4. $h$ defines an equivalence relation $\approx$ on $B$, its kernel. So in step 1, we need to arrange that, $\approx$ is a coarser equivalence than $\sim$, which is to say, for all $b_1,b_2 \in B$, we have $b_1 \sim b_2 \Rightarrow h(b_1) = h(b_2)$. This will not be $\Leftrightarrow$, because we need it to work for all $h$ satisfying the requirement in 3. **Not a misprint.**
5. Therefore the function $m([b]) = h(b)$ is well-defined on $S = B/{\sim}$, and $m \circ k = h$ by definition, and the uniqueness follows from the surjectivity of $k$.

We are left with how to define $\sim$ in part 1 so that it satisfies the requirement when it is used in part 4. Define $R \subseteq B \times B$ by
$$
R = \{ (f(a),g(a)) \mid a \in A \}
$$
($R$ is called $\rightsquigarrow$ by Simmons). Then take $\sim$ to be the "equivalence closure" of $R$, the finest equivalence relation containing $R$. If $\approx$ is the kernel of some $h : B \rightarrow X$ with $h \circ f = h \circ g$, then for all $a \in A$, $h(f(a)) = h(f(b))$, so $\approx$ contains $R$ and therefore is coarser than $\sim$, the property required in 4.

Comment: thank you for the explanation.  I posted a related question on coequalizer on how to define relations on the common codomain on the pair of maps here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620022/questions-about-the-differences-between-simmons-second-construction-and-romans can I ask you to take a look please if you have a moment.  Thank you.