# Questions about the differences between Simmons' second construction and Roman's construction of coequalizer for the category of $\textbf{Sets}.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

The following two blocks of quoted texts are from two different texts on describing coequalizer in the category of sets along with how each texts defines the concept of coequalizer.  I have some questions about why there seems to be subtle differences in their respective presentations.  The first is from Harold Simmon's *An introduction Category Theory*....

> $\quad$ [Simmons, **Definition 1**]  Given a parallel pair $${\stackrel{\large{A}\stackrel{\small\small f}{\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\longrightarrow}}\large{B}}{\small\small g}}$$ of arrows in a category $C$ $$\text{an equalizer} \quad \text{a coequalizer}$$ is an arrow $$S\xrightarrow{k}A \quad B\xrightarrow{k}S$$ which makes equal $f$ and $g$, and has the following universal property.
> $\quad$For each arrow $$X\xrightarrow{h}A \quad B\xrightarrow{h}X$$ which makes equal the parallel pair, there is a *unique arrow* $$X\xrightarrow{m}S \quad S\xrightarrow{m}X$$ such that $$h=k\circ m\quad h=m\circ k$$ holds.  This $m$ is the mediating arrow (or mediator) for the arrow $h$.
>
> [Simmons, **Example 1**] Let
> $${\stackrel{\large{A}\stackrel{\small\small f}{\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\longrightarrow}}\large{B}}{\small\small g}}$$
> be a parallel pair of functions, arrows in *Set*.  Let $\rightsquigarrow$ be the relation on $B$ given by $$\color{blue}{b_1 \rightsquigarrow b_2 \Longleftrightarrow (\exists a\in A)[b_1=f(a) \text{ and } b_2=g(a)]}$$ $b_1, b_2\in B.$  Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $B$ generated by $\rightsquigarrow.$  For an explicit description of $\rightsquigarrow,$ let
> $$B\xrightarrow{\beta}B/\sim$$ $$b\mapsto [b]$$ be the constructed quotient.
> $\quad$Consider any $a\in A$ and let $$b_1=f(a) \quad b_2=g(a)$$to obtain two elements of $b$ with $b_1\rightsquigarrow b_2.$ In particular we have $$b_1\sim b_2$$so that $$(\beta\circ f)(a)=\beta(b_1)=[b_1] =[b_2] =\beta(b_2)=(\beta\circ f)(a).$$To show that $\beta$ make equal $f$ and $g.$
> $\quad$Consider any function $h$ which does make equal $f$ and $g$. We show that $h$ factorizes uniquely through $\beta.$  Since $\beta$ is surjective, there can be at most one such factorization, so it suffices to show that one does exists.
> $\quad$ From this [blog post example,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620006/question-about-simmons-construction-of-his-first-construction-of-coequalizer-fo) suppose $$b_1\sim b_2$$ for $b_1, b_2\in B.$  Then $$b_1=f(a) \quad b_2=g(a)$$ for some $a\in A.$This gives $$h(b_1)=h(f(a))=h(g(a))=h(b_2)$$ and hence by this [blog post example,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620006/question-about-simmons-construction-of-his-first-construction-of-coequalizer-fo) gives a function $h^{\sharp}$ for the factorization.

and the one below is from Steven Roman's *An introduction to Language of Category Theory*

> 

[image]

> $\quad$[Roman, **Definition 2**] Let $C$ be a category, referring to the above diagram, the **coequalizer** of the diagram $$D=\{f:A\rightarrow B, g:A\rightarrow B\}$$ is an *initial cocone* $$I=\{C,k:B\rightarrow C\}$$ under $D$, that is, a pair $I$ for which $k$ left-equalizes $f$ and $g$ and for every $k:B\rightarrow C$ that left equalizes $f$ and $g$, there is a unique mediating morphism $\theta:C\rightarrow X$ for which $$\theta\circ k=h$$
>
> [Roman, **Example 2**]Consider the coequalizer in **Set**.  The condition that $h:B\rightarrow C$ left-equalizes $f$ and $f$ is $$h\circ f(a)=h\circ g(a),$$and that is equivalent to the statement that $h$ is constant on all sets of the form $\{f(a), g(a)\}$ for $a\in A$
> [image]

> It is well known that any set function $h:B\rightarrow C$ induces a *partition* of its domain $B$ whose blocks are the nonempty inverse images $h^{-1}(c),$ for $c\in C$.  Moreover, as shown in figure in the screenshot, $h$ left-equalizes $f$ and $g$ if  and only if for all $a\in A$, the elements $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ belongs to the same block of this $h$-induced partition off $B$.
> $\quad$As we shall see, the most "universal" such partition is the *finest* partition $P$ of $B$ for which the set $\{f(a), g(a)\}$ lies in a single block.  Note, however, that the fact that $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ lie in a single block $K$ of $P$ may force other other elements of $B$ to also lie in that block.  For example, if $g(a)=f(a')$ for some $a'\neq a$, then of course $f(a')\in K$ and so $g(a')$ must also like in $K$.
> $\quad$Perhaps the best way to get a handle on the partition $P$ is to to consider the corresponding equivalence relation $\equiv$ defined by $P$.  Thus, we begin by defining a binary relation on $B$ by $$\color{red}{b\approx b' \text{ if } b=b' \text{ or } \{b,b'\}=\{f(a), g(a)\} \text{ for some } a\in A}$$  This relation is both reflexive and symmetric, but it need not be transitive, so we ust pass the transitive closure $\equiv$.  Thus, $b_1\equiv b_n$ if there is a finite sequence $$b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$$ of elements of $B$ for which $b_1\approx b_{i+1}$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$
> $\quad$Now, the function $h$ left-equalizes $f$ and $g$ if and only if $h$ is constant on the *equivalence classes* of this equivalence relation.  Moreover, the most "universal" choice for $h$ is any function that assigns *different* values to these equivalence classes.  Perhaps the simplest way to define such a function, which we denote by $\pi$ is to send each element of a particular equivalence class $E$ to the equivalence class $E$ itself, that is $\pi(b)=[b],$ where $[b]$ is the equivalence class containing $b$.
> $\quad$The function $\pi$ is called the **canonical projection** associated with the equivalence relation or the partition and $P$ is denoted by $B/\equiv$.  Hence $\pi:B\rightarrow B/\equiv$ is defined by $$\pi(b)=[b]$$
> To see that $\pi$ is indeed a coequalizer of $f$ and $g$, if $h: B\rightarrow X$ left-equalizes $f$ and $g$, then $h$ is constant on the aforementioned equivalence classes and so the function $\color{Purple}{\theta:(B/\equiv)\rightarrow X}$ defined by $$\theta([b])=h(b)$$ is well-defined.  Moreover, $h=\theta\circ \pi.$  As to uniqueness, if $h=\tau\circ\pi$ for some $\tau:B/\equiv\rightarrow X,$ then $$\theta([b])=h(b)=\tau([b])$$ for all $b\in B$ and so $\tau=\theta.$  Hence $(B/\equiv,,\pi:B\rightarrow B/\equiv)$ is a coequalizer of $f$ and $g$.

**Questions**.  I just have two questions.  The first is, in Simmons' construction, he defines the relation $\color{blue}{b_1 \rightsquigarrow b_2 \Longleftrightarrow (\exists a\in A)[b_1=f(a) \text{ and } b_2=g(a)]}$, compare with Roman's $\color{red}{b\approx b' \text{ if } b=b' \text{ or } \{b,b'\}=\{f(a), g(a)\} \text{ for some } a\in A}.$  Roman's $b$ and $b'$ corresponds to Simmons' $b_1$ and $b_2$ respectively, but Roman has this extra condition $b=b'$. I would like to know if this extra condition in his definition would make any meaningful mathematical differences?
Second thing is, the map $\color{Purple}{\theta:B/\equiv\rightarrow X,}$ show that there is an extra set $B/\equiv$. So if we draw out all of the commutative diagram, where is the set $B/\equiv$ suppose to be drawn at?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simmons starts with $\rightsquigarrow$, which is in general not reflexive, symmetric or transitive, and takes what I call the "equivalence closure" $\sim$, the smallest reflexive, symmetric, transitive relation containing $\rightsquigarrow$. In Roman's approach, he starts with the relation $\approx$, which is reflexive (because he added $(b,b)$ to it by adding $(b,b')$ for every $b=b'$) and symmetric (because it also has $(g(a),f(a))$ in it by how it is defined), and then takes the transitive closure $\equiv$ of $\approx$.

Now, the relation, $\approx$ is the "reflexive-symmetric closure" of $\rightsquigarrow$, the $\subseteq$-least (*i.e.* what I call the finest) relation containing $\rightsquigarrow$ that is reflexive and symmetric. So what you need to show is that for any relation $R \subseteq Y \times Y$, the transitive closure of the reflexive-symmetric closure of $R$ is the same as the equivalence closure of $R$.

It's best to try proving it yourself, look here if you get stuck:

> Let's use $E(R)$ mean the equivalence closure of $R$, $S(R)$ for the reflexive-symmetric closure and $T(S(R))$ for the transitive closure of the reflexive-symmetric closure. By a direct calculation with Roman's definition, $T(S(R))$ is reflexive and symmetric and $R \subseteq T(S(R))$, so $E(R) \subseteq T(S(R))$. In the other direction, since $E(R)$ is symmetric and reflexive and $R \subseteq E(R)$, we have $S(R) \subseteq E(R)$, and since $E(R)$ is also transitive we have $T(S(R)) \subseteq E(R)$.

Therefore Simmons's $\sim$ and Roman's $\equiv$ are the exact same relation.

As for $B/{\equiv}$, it is intended to be the definition of $C$ in this specific case (just as $B/{\sim}$ is the definition of $X$ in Simmons's book), so you either draw it in place of $C$ or not at all.

Comment: thank you so much for the clarifications.  Most accounts on constructing coequalizer stick with how Simmoms does it and the way Roman did it was confusing because of that slight difference of being very specific on how the elements in the relations are to be related instead of them simply being in the same elements of a partition.  Also, Simmons did not stated that he is taking equivalene closure of his defined relations or at least not explicitly.